# Can the symbol $∈$ mean relation between elements?

Tags: asymptotics

Long time no see math concepts.

but as I want to improve in programing I need to get into some math concepts and symbols for understanding time complexity.

I saw this explanation in a problem that I solved:

*"Because of $h ∈ O(n)$, the space complexity is $O(n)$."*

Does this mean that $h$ relates to $O(n)$?

In such a way that if $n$ grows $h$ can grow, and if $n$ decreases $h$ can decrease?

I make sense to me but as far as I know, this symbol ($∈$) was used to tell a number belongs to a certain set

like $x$ belongs to real numbers, $x \in \mathbb R$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$h\in O(n)$ means that $h$ is *in* (is a member of) $O(n).$  $O(n)$ is a space/set, while  $x$ is an object or member in that space/set. But $O(n) \notin O(n)$.  So $h$ and $O(n)$ are not both elements of $O(n$. Likewise, $\mathbb R$ is the set of real numbers, and the notation $x\in \mathbb R$ means that $x$ is an number/object that resides in the set $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Okay, I think I understood than. It is O(N) because h is contained in O(N) set

Comment: So it doesn't mean that if any relation between n and h. only that it belongs to the set.

Comment: Yes, you've got it!